# How to run multiple debuggers simultaneously in CLion?

Tags: c++, clion

I am running a large project in CLion with 10 small projects inside. Each small project has a main function. These small projects should run in sequence, say a->b->c->d->... to ensure the large project run properly.

Currently when I try to debug this large project, I have to manually start the debug session of each small project in sequence, which is annoying.

My question is, is there any convenient way that it can start the debug processes of these small projects for me automatically by one click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "Before Launch" in your Run/Debug configuration to add dependent projects.

From CLion [web help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/run-debug-configurations-dialog.html):

> ### Before Launch
>
> Specify which tasks must be performed before applying the run/debug configuration. The specified tasks are performed in the order they appear in the list.
>
> **Run Another Configuration.** Select this option to have another run/debug configuration executed. In the dialog that opens, select the configuration to run.
> This option is available only if you have already at least one run/debug configuration in the current project.